remotepc by idrive fails to install on raspberrypi 3B+ by deb or terminal
hardware: raspberry pi 3 b+
os: 64 raspberry with desktop downloaded from raspberry July 2024 with the new installer
app / package that fails: remotepc from idriveinc
Previous to this was using RealVNC host and viewer without an issue. Gotten too expensive
3b+ powers and runs fine: Did the update and upgrade without any issues. browser, gthumb, libraoffice all run fine.
Went to idrive/remotepc website and downloaded the 64 deb package (combined host and viewer) advertised as for Raspberry.  Also after failure tried reinstalling the os and tried the host and viewer separtely.  Everytime the gui would show install starting then halts about halfway thru (by bar graph) and whole system locks up (no mouse, touch screen, or keyboard response).
Tried again after fresh raspberry os install to install from terminal with sudo apt install ./remotepc-host # command (from the idrive website instructions) which just never completes.
Note, over the same time able to install and run remotepc on my ubuntu 22 decade old HP laptop (AMD) as well as on Samsung galaxy tablet and galaxy S22+ phone (both with latest as of 7-24 android os).

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

You don't mention any Ubuntu product details at all, the only OS you mention is Raspberry Pi OS which is Debian based & from the Raspberry Pi Foundation, ie. isn't a Ubuntu product/release. If you're using Ubuntu on your pi, you should provide details of what Ubuntu product & release you're asking about.
